# How to send ui-router resolve values into directives?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I am trying to resolve the templateUrl in the `ui-router resolve` and pass it to the `directive`.

```
.state('app.student', {
            url : '/dashboard/:studentId',
            abstract : true,
            templateUrl : 'student.html',
            resolve : {
                template    : function (){
                    return {
                        student_header : 'student-header.html'
                    };
                }
            }
        })
```

If I use it in the directive which will be inside the child state, I am getting error that `unkownProvider : templateProvider`

```
.directive('myDirective', function(headerTemplate) {
        return {
          templateUrl : headerTemplate.student_header
        }
}
```

Comment: It is classic problem: you don't have to decide which template is loaded in templateUrl/template. Make several directives - or a single one with $templateRequest in link. Let route controller pass the needed information to the directive through its attributes.

Comment: As @estus already said, you should use a controller to pass data to directives since controllers control the interactions between the model and the view. If the direcitve needs data then use a controller to pass it in. The controller has access to the model e.g. though a service which holds the data and hence can be shared between different controllers and other services.